# How to hide/show child views from parent view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I created a custom view that shows content and 2 buttons (prev and next). Please find the code for the struct below:

```
struct PageNavigator<Content: View>: View {
var prevAction: () -> Void
var nextAction: () -> Void
private let content: () -> Content

init(prevAction: @escaping () -> Void, nextAction: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.prevAction = prevAction
    self.nextAction = nextAction
    self.content = content
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        content()

        HStack {
            Button(action: { self.prevAction() }) {
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
                    Text("Prev")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
            }

            Spacer()


            Button(action: { self.nextAction() }) {
                HStack{
                    Text("Next")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                }
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }.padding()
}
```

And this is how it's being used from a parent view

```
        PageNavigator(prevAction: {
            if (self.pageToDisplay > 0){
                self.pageToDisplay = self.pageToDisplay - 1
            }else{
                self.pageToDisplay = 0
            }
        }, nextAction: {
            self.pageToDisplay = self.pageToDisplay + 1
        }){
            //content to display
            Spacer()
            if(self.pageToDisplay < self.messages.count){
                //show walkthrough
                MessageView(title: self.messages[self.pageToDisplay].title , content: self.messages[self.pageToDisplay].message)
            }else{
                if(self.pageToDisplay == self.messages.count){
                    TermsAgreementView(pageToDisplay: self.$pageToDisplay)
                }else if(self.pageToDisplay == self.messages.count + 1){
                    SetBaseCurrencyView()
                }else if(self.pageToDisplay == self.messages.count + 2){
                    SmartRemindersView()
                }else if(self.pageToDisplay == self.messages.count + 3){
                    GetStartedView()
                }
                else{
                    MessageView(title: "Test page \(self.messages.count)", content: "Test")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
```

Now what I wanted to achieve was to add a property that will allow me to show or hide either the prev or next button from the parent view. What would be an effective way to do this? I tried adding @Binding showNextButton: Bool and @Binding showPrevButton: Bool. But it's not working as expected.

Thanks in advance!

**FOLLOW UP / UPDATE**

So the solution proposed below worked but I have a follow up. So I created 2 properties showNextBtn and showPrevBtn to show/hide the 2 nav buttons. But I would like to make them optional such that I don't have to provide those 2 parameters. So if the 2 parameters are not provided, the 2 buttons should then be hidden. I updated the code as below:

```
struct PageNavigator<Content: View>: View {
var prevAction: () -> Void
var nextAction: () -> Void
private let content: () -> Content

@Binding var showNextBtn: Bool?
@Binding var showPrevBtn: Bool?

init(showNextBtn: Binding<Bool?>?, showPrevBtn: Binding<Bool?>?, prevAction: @escaping () -> Void, nextAction: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.prevAction = prevAction
    self.nextAction = nextAction
    self.content = content
    if showNextBtn != nil{
        self._showNextBtn = showNextBtn!
    }else{
        self._showNextBtn = Binding.constant(false)
    }

    if showPrevBtn != nil{
        self._showPrevBtn = showPrevBtn!
    }else{
        self._showPrevBtn = Binding.constant(false)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        content()

        HStack {
            if self.showPrevBtn!{
                Button(action: { self.prevAction() }) {
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
                        Text("Prev")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                }
            }

            Spacer()

            if self.showNextBtn!{
                Button(action: { self.nextAction() }) {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Next")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }.padding()
}
```

And I use the above view on the parent view as thus:

```
        PageNavigator(showNextBtn: $showNextBtn, showPrevBtn: $showPrevBtn, prevAction: {
            if (self.pageToDisplay > 0){
                self.pageToDisplay = self.pageToDisplay - 1
            }else{
                self.pageToDisplay = 0
            }
        }, nextAction: {
            self.pageToDisplay = self.pageToDisplay + 1...
```

But I get the error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Binding?'" for the $showNextBtn and $showPrevBtn parameters. Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieving what you asking for using @Binding.
This is how i did it

```
struct PageNavigator<Content: View>: View {
var prevAction: () -> Void
var nextAction: () -> Void
private let content: () -> Content

@Binding var showNext : Bool

init(showNext : Binding<Bool> , prevAction: @escaping () -> Void, nextAction: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.prevAction = prevAction
    self.nextAction = nextAction
    self.content = content

    self._showNext = showNext
}

 var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ...

            if self.showNext {
                Button(action: { self.nextAction() }) {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Next")
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                    }
                }
            }

        ...
    }
}
```

Now from the parent :

```
@State var showNext : Bool = true
...
PageNavigator( showNext : self.$showNext, prevAction: {
        if (self.pageToDisplay > 0){
            --->
            self.showNext.toggle() // = false , true
        }else{
            self.pageToDisplay = 0
        }
    }, nextAction: {
        self.pageToDisplay = self.pageToDisplay + 1

    },content: {
        ...
    }
```